# How to specifically provides multiple query of the attributes using PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, tabular

I have a table named student with its attributes and data:

```
table student
----------------
student_id    |    student_name    |    year    |    exam    |    level    |    mark    |    gred  
1111               Alicia               2017         First          6            90           A
1111               Alicia               2016         Final          5            80           A
1111               Alicia               2016         Mid            5            87           A
1111               Alicia               2016         First          5            70           B
1111               Alicia               2015         Final          4            40           D
1111               Alicia               2015         Mid            4            60           C
1111               Alicia               2015         First          4            70           B
2222               Kelvin               2017         First          6            86           A
2222               Kelvin               2016         Final          5            80           A
2222               Kelvin               2016         Mid            5            80           A
2222               Kelvin               2016         First          5            70           B
2222               Kelvin               2015         Final          4            38           D
2222               Kelvin               2015         Mid            4            65           C
2222               Kelvin               2015         First          4            75           B
```

I need to display the marks of each student based on their exam and level in a table.

```
No  |  Student's Name      |First-Term Exam L4 |Mid-Term Exam L4 | Final Exam L4   |First-Term Exam L5 |Mid-Term Exam L5 | Final Exam L5   |First-Term Exam L6
    |                      |  Mark   |  Grade  |  Mark  |  Grade |  Mark  |  Grade |  Mark   |  Grade  |  Mark  |  Grade |  Mark  |  Grade |  Mark  |  Grade |
1      Alicia                  70         B        60        C       40        D       70         B        87        A       80        A        90        A    
2      Kelvin                  75         B        65        C       38        D       70         B        80        A       80        A        86        A
```

I need to output the table like this, but I can't figure it out on how to query them.

Comment: Get all rows and order by student and then by date. Then you can start a new row when the student changes.

Comment: can you provides me the example of the query?